# hive managed table record count result is not showing

Tags: hive, count, aggregate

I'm working on HDP 3.0 kerberized cluster and trying to run hive count query.
while running count query i found that it's not showing result for managed table but same query working for external table

```
CREATE TABLE rule_config_value (
config_column STRING,
config_value STRING
) STORED AS ORC;

INSERT INTO TABLE rule_config_value VALUES ("empid","5");
INSERT INTO TABLE rule_config_value VALUES ("state","NJ");
INSERT INTO TABLE rule_config_value VALUES ("country","United States");

select count(*) from rule_config_value;
```

output getting :

```
+------+
| _c0  |
+------+
+------+
```

Steps tried but didn't got any success:

```
analyze table rule_config_value compute statistics;
analyze table rule_config_value compute statistics for columns config_column,config_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select `_c0` from rule_config_value;
```

Comment: thanks for replying but normal select query is working. only count is not working.